# E-mail signature marked as spam

Tags: outlook, office365

I have recently deployed a new corporate e-mail signature and have found that it is being flagged as junk/span by O365 recipients.

Is there a way that I can find out what exactly is in the signature that is being flagged? All the hyperlinks are HTTPS.

I have tested it in gmail and hotmail so far. Both have received the e-mail just fine.

Comment: Tell them not to flag it. Don’t you have office 365?

Comment: Contact Office 365 support and ask them what's the problem.

Comment: @0m3r No, I don't have 365. Using on-premise exchange. I have tried creating a 365 trial account to test this but still to no avail.

Comment: @VictorIvanidze I'll give this a shot. However, given my past experiences with Microsoft support, this can take a very long time to resolve.

Comment: Generally speaking, email service providers will not tell you what exactly they don't like when they classify your email as spam --- spammers would abuse this to get their junk through spam filters. It could also be something completely unrelated to your signature. That said, your question is impossible to answer since you don't give details on what your email signature looks like.